# HTML to create repeating header + detail rows for orders/details

Tags: html, css

I'm not too familiar with HTML so I'm reaching out to the HTML wizards for help. My goal is to create a table that shows Order Header information on one line with Order detail information on rows below that. Then that would repeat for every order. Here's what I have so far. I'm asking for a nudge in the right direction to get the Order # to repeat for each new order.

This is within a piece of software that uses the command {BEGIN*REPEAT} to repeat rows of data.

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
{BEGIN*HTML}

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid green;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans- serif;
    }
    td {
      padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
    }
    th {
      background-color: purple;
      color: white;
      padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
    }
    text {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    p {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<!--Used to add image
<table style="border:0px">
            <tr style="border:0px">
            <td style="border:0px"><p><img src="" style="position:relative;      left:-20px; width:475px;"</td>
        </tr>
<table>

Used to right justify numeric fields: style="text-align:right;"
-->

<p>Below is a list of orders created for your customers.</p>

<p><b>Order Details</b>
</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ord.#</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Cust.</th>
      <th>Ship-to</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>ST</th>
      <th>ExpectedShip</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>UnitPrice</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th>{ORDNUMBER}</th>
    </tr>

    {BEGIN*REPEAT}


    <tr>
      <td>{ORDNUMBER}</td>
      <td>{OrdDateYYYYMMDD}</td>
      <td>{NAMECUST}</td>
      <td>{SHPNAME}</td>
      <td>{SHPCITY}</td>
      <td>{SHPSTATE}</td>
      <td>{EXPDATE}</td>
      <td>{ITEM}</td>
      <td>{ORIGQTY}</td>
      <td>{UNITPRICE}</td>
      <td>{LOCATION}</td>
    </tr>

    {END*REPEAT}
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<p></p>
{END*HTML}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you to get started.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: order;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
td:first-child:after {
  content: "ORD000" counter(order);
}
td:nth-child(2):after {
  content: "20060717";
}
tr:first-child td:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This Column increases by 1</td>
    <td>This Column just repeats</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```